# How to create docker image with nodejs 12, java, gcc, g++,python3, monocs

Tags: java, node.js, docker

I am trying to dockerize my NodeJs & Express API . In my API iam using https://www.npmjs.com/package/compile-run package to compile and run C,
Cpp,Java,JavaScript(Node.js env), Python languages.
This package requires all 5 compilers(gcc,g++,nodejs,python3,javac) installed on the server. If any compiler misses, it throws error.

In my local(undockerized) the API is working completely fine on both windows & ubuntu(As I have installed compilers on them).

I am trying to replicate the same on my docker image. But I am stuck.

Look at my
**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I think node-12 image comes along with gcc, g++,python3 and nodejs(obviously).
But the issue is with **java**. I am not able to compile java code.

so I tried it this way

```
FROM node:12
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
# RUN java -version
RUN apt -y install default-jre
RUN apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
RUN java -version

WORKDIR /app


COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

But I am not able to install open-jdk or open-jre with apt/apt-get.
What is the right way to configure docker?

This is my nodeJS API repository https://github.com/yogendramaarisetty/online-compiler-api

Comment: Could multistage builds Help ?

Comment: No I have no idea

Comment: You could use one stage for each language you need instead of taking one and adding more languages

Comment: Can you answer with more detailed implementation. I am new to docker.

Comment: I'd write a separate `Dockerfile` for each component of this, and use a tool like Docker Compose to run all of the resulting containers together.  You can build the separate parts of this `FROM node`, `FROM openjdk`, and so on.

Comment: @DavidMaze OP doesn't want multiple containers. OP wants to host an online compiler. The specifics are undefined here, but I assume something like [Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I want to host an online compiler API , my request body has language id, source_code, time_limit and response would be like stdout, stderr, exitcode.
My API runs child process to execute the code by running shell commands in 5 different languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you must update the package list with `apt-get update`, then you can install openjdk-8. openjdk-11 isn't available with that distribution of node. I used `docker run -it node:12 /bin/bash` to see what there was,

```
FROM node:12
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

For example,

```
$ cat Dockerfile                                         
FROM node:12
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
$ docker build --tag mynode:1.0 .
$ docker run -it mynode:1.0 /bin/bash                                    
root@d70858199dd1:/# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0+deb9u1-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
root@d70858199dd1:/# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_265
root@d70858199dd1:/#
```

If you really do need Java 11, there are multiple ways and places to get openjdk-11. One is bell-sw. For example,

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM node:12
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libasound2 libxtst6
RUN wget https://download.bell-sw.com/java/11.0.7+10/bellsoft-jdk11.0.7+10-linux-amd64.deb && \
    apt install ./bellsoft-jdk11.0.7+10-linux-amd64.deb
$ docker build --tag mynode:1.1 .
$ docker run -it mynode:1.1 /bin/bash
root@37771ce98727:/# java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-LTS, mixed mode)
root@37771ce98727:/# javac -version
javac 11.0.7
```